# plotting bar chart with matplotlib with python 3.7

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

i plotted a bar chart , and i wantes every bar to have a student name . 
this is my code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot
    import numpy as np
    names=["avi","jose","bob","nick","zelda","mark"]
    pos=np.arange(6)+0.5
    matplotlib.pyplot.bar(pos,(4,8,12,3,17,6),align="center",color="red")
    matplotlib.pyplot.title("hight of students in unches",color="blue")
    matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel("hight in inches",color="red")
    matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel("students",color="red")
    matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params(axis="x",color="white")
    matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params(axis="y",color="white")
    matplotlib.pyplot.yticks(pos,(names))
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

but i keep getting the names on the side instead above the bar[image]

thanks for the help :)|

Comment: Because you are using `matplotlib.pyplot.yticks(pos,(names))`, you see the names on the y axis

Answer (score 0):

Taking the example code from [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html):

```
names=["avi","jose","bob","nick","zelda","mark"]
pos=np.arange(6)+0.5
bars = matplotlib.pyplot.bar(pos,(4,8,12,3,17,6),align="center",color="red")
matplotlib.pyplot.title("hight of students in unches",color="blue")
matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel("hight in inches",color="red")
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel("students",color="red")

for i,bar in enumerate(bars):
    matplotlib.pyplot.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2., 1.05*bar.get_height(),
                names[i],ha='center', va='bottom')

matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params(axis="x",color="white")
matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params(axis="y",color="white")
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

[image]